# How to use compact map on custom type?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am about reduce code by using compact map. But I can't convert custom struct into `[String: String]` type.

```
struct Sample {

    let key: String
    let value: String
}

let all = [Sample]()
```

I want to make array all samples into dictionary. So I used compact map & It returns error

> Cannot convert value of type '[[String : String]]' to specified type
>   '[String : String]'

But I don't know exactly what I need to use.

```
let dictionary: [String: String] = all.compactMap{[$0.key: $0.value]}
```

Please help me to find out correct solutions. Thank you all in advance...

Comment: `.init(uniqueKeysWithValues: all.map{($0.key,$0.value)})`

Comment: @LeoDabus, Wow, Thank you very much! Just have a doubt, Reduce or map which is efficient way? Any idea to find it?

Comment: Reduce is fine. It all depends on your sequence. This requires that your sequence has uniqueKeysWithValues while reduce will overwrite the previous values without a warning

Comment: if your sequence might have duplicated keys Dictionary has another initializer where you can decide to keep the first value or the last `.init(all.map{($0.key,$0.value)}) { first, last in first }`

Comment: if you would like to add multiple values to the same key `all.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key, default: []].append($1.value) }`

Comment: Or `let dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: all.map { ($0.key, $0.value) })`. Or `let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: all) { $0.key }`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce):

```
let dictionary = all.reduce(into: [:]) { dict, elem in
   dict[elem.key] = elem.value
}
```